# How to use Amyuni PDF converter 4.0 in PowerBuilder 2017 without "run as Administrator"

Tags: pdf, printing

We have an application in PB 2017 that using Amyuni PDF Converter 4.0 to print the report in PDF file. The application works well until we upgrade the PC to Windows 10. There is a message "Printer not activated, error code -30" when printing the PDF. If we run the program "as administrator", it works. But there are some users who cannot run as administrator and so they cannot print the reports in PDF.

Any advice for this issue?

Comment: Try this: https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3021&p=9523&hilit=registry+permissions#p9523